# My toolbar is not relate with my product list

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list, toolbar

I have a custom product list page that contains 55 products. But now I have problem. Look at this pictures below :

1. In page one it shows 55 items, but i've chose the limit is 24.

[image: On page 1]

2. In page two, it shows 55 items, but look the counters below :
   [image: Page two]

It says items 25 to 79 of 55 total.

Here is my scripts when I call my filtered products :

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
if ($id) {
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('n_customer_brand', $id);
            $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count();
            }

?>
```

and this is my scripts to call my toolbar :

```
<?php  
           // Custom Way
        $toolbar = $this->getToolbarBlock();
        $toolbar->setCollection($_productCollection );
        $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
        $pager = $layout->createBlock('page/html_pager');
        $toolbar->setChild('product_list_toolbar_pager', $pager);
        echo $toolbar->toHtml();

    ?>
```

NOTE : I've change it to this script below, but it shows a wrong count and pager is not showing.

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
```

and my block has an extends **Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to chnage your collection as below

```
$page = 1; //example 
$size = 10; //exmple
if(isset($_GET['p'])){
    $page = $_GET['p'];
}
if(isset($_GET['limit'])){
    $size = $_GET['limit'];
}

$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('n_customer_brand', $id)
                        ->setPageSize($size)
                        ->setCurPage($page);
$_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count();
```

Comment: @syahidahhumairoh you are always welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Syahidah, Please try this-

```
<reference name="content">

<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                    <!--
                        <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>10</limit></action>
                        <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>8</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>10</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>20</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>30</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>16</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>24</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>grid</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                    -->
                </block>
                <!--action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action-->
                <action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
```

I am Upding my xml file same as Catlog file. it's Working Here

Comment: That's not work for me.

Fatal error: Call to a member function getSize() on null in /home/........